# How to gain access back to root (admin) user in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I had one admin user with `username = root (had admin privileges)` and `password =admin` then i created new user with `username =root (have no privileges)` and `password =root`. but what happened now I have lost access to `root user(admin)` and i am able to access only `root user` which is newly created.now i am unable to do anything with this `newly created root user`. it show access denied for every operation. so is there any way to gain access to `root(admin)` user or give admin privileges to new root user or reset databases and start by new. I tried many solution but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Complete account name includes both username part and host part. See [Specifying Account Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html) and the difference between USER() and CURRENT_USER().

Check complete names for both `root` accounts. Then log in by the way which makes "old" `root` account matched one only.

For example, if "old" is `'root'@'%'` and "new" is `'root'@'localhost'` or `'root'@'127.0.0.1'` then disable network connections (`--skip-networking=ON` in the service command line) and connect using named pipes or shared memory (on Windows) or Unix socket files (on Unix). Or connect to the server remotely.